# Library reference Lib\Copy of google-play-services_lib could not be found

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services

When I try to import one project from eclipse to Android Studio , it shows me this error:

> Project BLE_Sample_Android-master: path/project.properties: Library
>   reference Lib\Copy of google-play-services_lib could not be found Path
>   is path\Lib\Copy of google-play-services_lib which resolves to
>   \BLE_Sample_Android-master\Lib\Copy of google-play-services_lib

Already paste copy of `google-play-services_lib.jar` in `project/libs`, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some research and found out that one way to resolve the issue is to remove the line in the '*project.properties*' file that was making reference to the '*google-play-services_lib*' library.

Here's where I found my answer: [Android Studio - Library reference ../google-play-services_lib could not be found importing project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26443718/android-studio-library-reference-google-play-services-lib-could-not-be-foun)

You may also check the Official site how to migrate from Eclipse ADT to Android Studio, here's the link: http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html

Answer (score 0):

In your `build.gradle` file in `dependencies` file add this line

```
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
```

You don't need to add `.jar` libs.

Then, choose `Tools -> Android -> SDK Manager`

Check if Google Services Library is already installed:

[image]

Hope it help

Comment: If you're adding GMS via Maven you need "Google Repository" not "Google Play services".